# Enabling Intellisense In Visual Studio for GLSL Code

Tags: visual-studio

I'm quite fond of all the interactive help Visual Studio gives when programming C++ code...

I find I'm doing more and more GLSL (OpenGL shader language) coding and I'd like to extend the Visual Studio editing goodness to GLSL source work.

I searched the web and didn't find any very good extensions or tweaks that provide decent Intellisense coloring, hovering, completion, etc. for GLSL specifically.

I've gotten a bit further by telling Visual Studio to treat .glsl files as C++ code, and piecing together a header file that defines some things that are provided by the GLSL environment, though I have some work to do to make it complete.  It's not compiled into the actual shaders by virtue of a pre-processor condition:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "GLSL_Intellisense_Hacks.h"    // Facilitate Intellisense in the shader code
#endif
```

My question is this:

Is there a better way out there that I just haven't run across yet?  A not-so-well-known extension, or an already developed "GLSL_Intellisense_Hacks.h" file?

Thanks for any knowledge you're willing to share on accomplishing more efficient GLSL coding.

-Noel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used a hack file for a while, but it turns out we've finally been able to get virtually 100% coverage with Intellisense by adding the glm library, which defines objects that cover all the data and syntax used in shaders - including swizzled vector accesses.

The only statement that evokes one warning is the #version pre-processor statement.  Haven't figured out how to avoid that one yet.

Comment: Hi, old thread, but would you happen to have examples/instructions on how to set up intellisense like you did? Quite interested in this, not sure what you meant by "adding glm library".

Comment: Include this library in your compilation...
https://github.com/g-truc/glm